# Invalid certificate for my MAUI application

Tags: certificate, maui, desktop-application

I followed [these steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/windows/deployment/publish-visual-studio-folder) and got a folder with a .cer file and a .msix file.
I installed the cer file both for current user and local machine but when I run the .msix I got that it cannot verify the certificate.
I also loaded one generated with the digicert desktop app, nothing to do.
How can I get a certificate that allows me to install my app in other computers?

Answer (score 1):

I found it, when you install the certificate you have to select local computer and then Trusted people as archive.

Comment: 1.Yes, when installing the certificate, you need to choose [the local machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKLYG.png) and then select trusted root certification as you said. 2. You can add more details to your post and check [Accept Your Own Answers](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) as it's helpful to others facing the same problem.